# left to right swinging shower arm?

Tags: bathroom, shower

remodeling master bathroom and installed 2 rain shower heads with 16" arms on a 54" wall. They are evenly spaced 13.5" as shown below. It's a little tight on the wall sides. I would have liked to had them at 16" from the wall but it would be a lot of work to move them now. Are there any shower arm adapters that allow you to rotate the shower arm left to right? Are arms that articulate left to right? I able to find arms that adjust up and down but nothing for horizontal adjustment.

```
<-13.5-> <-13.5-> <-13.5-> <-13.5->
___________________________________
|       |                 |       |
|       |                 |       |
|       O                 O       |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: It's easy to find "articulated shower heads" that move vertically, but you need horizontal. Can you mount a vertical one sideways?

Comment: I might try one of those. My concern was that the right side will be swung out to left and the weight might cause it to go loose?